# Flink, why a CoMap returns "DataStream with Product with Serializable" instead of just a DataStream?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to understand why `eventStream.connect(otherStream).map(_ => Right(2), _ => Left("2"))` does not generate a `DataStream[Either[String, Int]]` but a `DataStream[Either[String, Int]] with Product with Serializable`. 
I'm using some API that does accept a `DataStream[T]` and if I pass them a `DataStream[T] with Product with Serializable` I got a compile time error. Can someone explain and maybe give me some hint ?

I show you an example:

```
class FlinkFoo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // Silly int source
    val eventStream: DataStream[Int] = env.addSource((sc: SourceContext[Int]) => {
      while (true) sc.collect(1)
    })

    // Silly String source
    val otherStream: DataStream[String] = env.addSource((sc: SourceContext[String]) => {
      while (true) sc.collect("1")
    })

    // I need to connect two stream and then flatten them
    val connectedStream2: DataStream[Either[String, Int] with Product with Serializable] = eventStream.connect(otherStream).map(_ => Right(2), _ => Left("2"))

    /* Compile time error !!!!
     * found   : org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[Either[String,Int] with Product with Serializable]
     * [error]  required: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream[Either[?,?]]
     * [error] Note: Either[String,Int] with Product with Serializable <: Either[?,?], but class DataStream is invariant in type T.
     * [error] You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
     * [error]     fooMethod(connectedStream2)
     * [error]               ^
     **/
    fooMethod(connectedStream2)
  }

  def fooMethod[T, P](dataStream: DataStream[Either[T, P]]): Unit = {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to add Flink scala implicit serializers and `TypeInformation` to your scope as follows

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
```

The `TypeUtils` [object](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/scala/typeutils/package-summary.html) is called by the above imported package object; they provide Serializer and required type information for `Either` as long as for many other entities.

You need those conversions to resolve `Either` type after Flink generic type resolution and you might explicitly add return type to your assigment in order to achieve that conversion.

```
val yourEitherStream: DataStream[Either[String, Int]] =
  eventStream
    .connect(otherStream)
    .map(_ => Right(2), _ => Left("2"))
```

`with Product with Serializable` *mix-in* is a refuse of [Scala 2.11 issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9173), resolved by 2.12 (but you can't use it with Flink [right now](http://Add%20support%20for%20Scala%202.12)).

Comment: Thank you, import that package works ! But the type of the val must be explicit in order to avoid the compile time error:
    val connectedStream2: DataStream[Either[String, Int]] = eventStream.connect(otherStream).map(_ => Right(2), _ => Left("2"))